# Ansible: How to control execution of dependant role

Tags: ansible

I have defined a role to deploy a stack. It has flow like this:

1) Validate Minimal require things
2) Launch the stack
3) Post configuration

I have created another role to validate the network connectivity before launching the stack (before step 1) and after launching the stack (before step 3).

I am not aware how can I achieve this.

However I have break the `network-validation` role into the two roles according to the tasks. In `network-validation` role certain tasks has to be executed before step 1 ( mandatory Network check), which is created as role A, and certain tasks will be executed based on the condition, those tasks are in role B.

Still I am not able to figure out how to execute the role B based on condition.

Currently I am trying to execute role based on condition as below, but it's throwing error.

`/roles/deploy-stack/meta/main.yml` file looks like this:

```
dependencies:

  - { role: 'network-validation-B', when: ("CREATE_COMPLETE" in stack_list.stdout) }
```

`stack.yml` looks like this:

```
- hosts: controller
  roles:
    - { role: network-validation-B, when: ("CREATE_COMPLETE" in stack_list.stdout) }
    - deploy-stack
```

When I am trying to execute the playbook, it is throwing below error,

```
root@ansible-dev:/etc/ansible# ansible-playbook stack.yml

PLAY [controller] ***********************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [10.17.10.150]

TASK: [network-validation-B | Validating Network Connectivity] *********
fatal: [10.17.10.150 -> 10.17.10.85] => error while evaluating conditional: ("CREATE_COMPLETE" in stack_list.stdout)

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

It is not able to evaluate condition because `"when: ("CREATE_COMPLETE" in stack_list.stdout)"` condition will be true only if `"deploy-stack"` role executes first.

Comment: Do I understand the following correctly? You want to run `network-validation ` role before step 1 always, but only if certain conditions are met before step 3?

Comment: It sounds like these 3 things all deserve their own separate roles and then you just call all of the roles (and your network-validation role) in order in the playbook. But yeah, a role included as a meta dependency will be ran before anything else in the role.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @SztupY you got it right. Certain task in `network-validation` role has to run before step 1 always (mandatory network check) , and remaining task has to run after step 3 only if Stack is successfully Created.  However currently I have created new role for (mandatory network check), I am executing it before step 1. Still I am not getting how to execute certain task in `network-validation` role once condition is met.  I am editing the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

can you make change like this:

```
- { role: 'network-validation-B', when: '"CREATE_COMPLETE" in stack_list.stdout' }
```